# Python Call By Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to pass a DataFrame (df1) to a function. In the function the DataFrame gets changed. This change should not be applied to the original (df1).
In c++ I can pass variables to functions with call_by_value. Unfortunately I don't get this pass in python.

```
def func1(df):
   #Change some values in the DataFrame

df1 = pd.DataFrame(some content...)

func1(df1) #df1 gets passed to func1

print(df1) #df1 does not have the same content after the function call as before the function call
```

The content in df1 should only be changed inside the function. When i print the DataFrame after i ran the function,
it should have the same values like before

Comment: Yes, of course, **python never uses call by value**. Or call by reference, for that matter. If you want an object to be copied, you need to do that **explicitly**. One simple solution is in your function, just do `df = df.copy()` as the first line.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: isn't the duplicate asking for the exact opposite?

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes, but it explains in detail Python evaluation strategy, which is *neither* call by reference nor call by value. There is only a single evaluation strategy, and you don't get to choose.